# Is there a way to create a value in the middle of doughnut on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, pie-chart

is there a way to made the value of "total" in the middle of doughnut chart instead part of the chart itself, I've try to create in a different series, but it won't work in doughnut chart. its very useful for me since the actual data keep update in 1 minute
data range selected A1:B4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONY1f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to create a scorecard chart using total value and overlay it on the doughnut chart.

[image]